# Failed to Push files to phone for debuging

Tags: intel-xdk

I get this error when trying to launch app on device:

```
Error 20: Failed to Push files. Please Retry. 
File: unknown Cause: ERROR (1) from 
"core:private:http-request": Http request failed Error at new ComponentError
```

I am using Windows version latest build - `1536`.

My Android phone is htc `4.0.2`.

Anyone facing this problem?

Comment: What are you using to "push" to the device? Are you using the Test tab or ???

Comment: Debug -> Launch App on Device / Debug App on Device

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try starting App Preview on the device before you launch the app in the Debug tab. I've seen situations where slow devices (typical of the very inexpensive devices) need to have App Preview already up and running before you try to launch the app in the Debug tab.

Another thing is to insure that you have App Preview Crosswalk installed on your device, without it you cannot make the Debug tab work. Go to the "Apps" or "Applications" or "Apps Manager" section in the Settings area of your Android device and review the list of applications installed on your device. You should find both App Preview and App Preview Crosswalk (App Preview Crosswalk does not have a corresponding icon in the app start space on your Android device).

Comment: How to install App Preview Crosswalk? I just install App Preview.

Comment: APX is normally installed automatically when you attempt to connect with the Debug tab. Did APX show up in the list of apps installed on your device? Or is it missing? Please provide more information.

Comment: It is not installed. I cant find App Preview Crosswalk. It did not prompt me to install any thing before.

Comment: You can download the current version of App Preview Crosswalk here: https://s3.amazonaws.com/xdk-apx-cdt/apx-0.25/AppAnalyzer.apk -- might be easiest to mail the link to your Android device and download and install it that way, otherwise you have to learn how to side load an APK using adb.